# MonoTouch: How can I monitor the keyboard and determine KeyPress events?

Tags: xamarin.ios

How can I monitor the keyboard and determine KeyPress events ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to monitor key press events for UITextView, then override the [`UITextViewDelegate`](http://docs.go-mono.com/MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextViewDelegate/Members)'s `ShouldChangeText()` method.

If you want to monitor key press events for UITextField, there's a similar method in [`UITextFieldDelegate`](http://docs.go-mono.com/MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextFieldDelegate/Members) called `ShouldChangeCharacters()`.

Find more info on the usage of these methods [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006897-CH3-SW6) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

Answer (score 1):

The **ShouldChangeCharacters** of UITextField is called BEFORE the text is changed and it is not the same as the **Changed** event of UITextView. This means that getting the text on the **ShouldChangeCharacters** or **ShouldChangeText** method, will allways return the text BEFORE the last key was pressed.

The UITextView has a **Changed** event like the KeyPress event. UITextField has not such event yet.

A workaround for the UITextField can be found here:
[bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=864](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=864)

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver
```

(UITextField.TextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, (notification) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Character received! {0}", notification.Object ==
TextField);
});